# How to read the kernel panic report?

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I've the following kernel panic

```
Anonymous UUID:       55E7769C-B596-6BC8-7C49-B7292D9F3A27

Sun May 27 14:37:28 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801ed88c2d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff803209c6d0, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff803209c6d0, CR3: 0x0000000207706000, CR4: 0x00000000000026e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000006, RCX: 0xffffff80333ed420, RDX: 0xffffff803357c8b8
RSP: 0xffffff912bab3ed0, RBP: 0x0000000000000005, RSI: 0xffffff803353487e, RDI: 0xffffff803357c8b8
R8:  0xffffff80316c4000, R9:  0x0000000000000003, R10: 0xffffff8033516340, R11: 0x0000000000000018
R12: 0xffffff80333ed420, R13: 0x00007fff6dc47eb8, R14: 0xffffff912bab3e50, R15: 0xffffff80333ed3e0
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff803209c6d0, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff803209c6d0, Error code: 0x0000000000000011, Fault CPU: 0x0 Kernel NX fault, PL: 0, VF: 2

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff912bab3980 : 0xffffff801ec6e166 
0xffffff912bab39d0 : 0xffffff801ed96714 
0xffffff912bab3a10 : 0xffffff801ed88a00 
0xffffff912bab3a90 : 0xffffff801ec20180 
0xffffff912bab3ab0 : 0xffffff801ec6dbdc 
0xffffff912bab3be0 : 0xffffff801ec6d99c 
0xffffff912bab3c40 : 0xffffff801ed88c2d 
0xffffff912bab3dc0 : 0xffffff801ec20180 
0xffffff912bab3de0 : 0xffffff803209c6d0 
Unaligned frame
Backtrace terminated-invalid frame pointer 0x5

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: coreduetd

Mac OS version:
17E202

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Fri Apr 13 19:32:32 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7134F18E-AAC2-3C5B-B2C4-ABB799B4B9DF
Kernel slide:     0x000000001ea00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801ec00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801eb00000
System model name: iMac10,1 (Mac-F2268CC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6274010351
last loaded kext at 2385259134: com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.5f3 (addr 0xffffff7fa1869000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  353
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  404.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBODD    439.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    439.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 439.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  700.74.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.nvenet    2.0.22
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.5f3
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.50.10
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.50.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    675.12
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: iMac10,1, BootROM IM101.00D0.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 3,06 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.52f9
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400, NVIDIA GeForce 9400
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A54463235363634485A2D3147364D3120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384A54463235363634485A2D3147364D3120
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 4.0.74.0-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.5f3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HDT721050SLA360, 500,11 GB
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SV300S37A120G, 120,03 GB
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: External
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Can anyone help me to understand how to read this report in order to understand what caused the crash? I've the kernel panic several days a month.

Comment: `coreduetd` is associated with the current thread, see [What is coreduetd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297391) for other's research about this process. Are you using iOS/macOS handoff features at the time of the crash?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel panics are generally not supposed to happen.

It can be impossible to determine the cause of a single kernel panic. They can be related to kernel bugs, version incompatibility, driver bugs and/or hardware problems.

As you have often recurring kernel panics, you should save the text of many of these kernel panics. Then you can compare them to each other to find a common thread, if any. For example, in this case the current process is coreduetd - is that always the case when it crashes? (then that could be the cause, although that would be due to Apple bugs).

The general error described in this kernel panic is a page fault - i.e. the kernel trying to access memory that isn't mapped for access by the kernel. This is due to kernel bugs or hardware error.

If it is always page faults, but various processes and device drivers - then that is an indication of either flawed OS installation or hardware error.

In your case I would recommend running the system for an extended period of time without any external devices of any kind plugged in (besides those necessary for the system to function obviously). If the kernel panic still occurs, that's a great data point.

In that case start the Mac in Recovery mode (hold down Cmd-R when booting). If kernel panics still happen in Recovery mode, it is much less likely that the problem is related to your software installation. Instead it is likely caused by hardware errors.

Hardware errors that cause page faults are usually defective RAM modules or lack of proper cooling. Check that fans are working properly, exhausts are not covered and temperature is nominal. If your computer has replaceable memory, try running with only one memory module plugged in. If crashes still occur, swap with another module.

Hopefully this should allow you to determine the true cause of the panics.

Comment: It's not impossible, just takes a bit of time and patience. There's a great write-up on how to diagnose a kernel panic [here](https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x27.html)

Comment: I did not say that it is impossible, but rather that it can be impossible. This is correct. No matter how much time you have, some times the necessary information for determining the cause of a kernel panic is not contained in the report. In these cases you could insert more debug output statements or attach a kernel debugger and hope for the kernel to panic again. Then that’s a new kernel panic...